# Generate font character map with by using PHP

Tags: unicode, truetype

I had searching a lot of time to find the solution to generate font character map table by using PHP. I just want PHP to generate font character map table automatically when I upload a font (like this picture:

[image]

And here is [an example](http://selapa.net/khmerfonts/charmap.php?font=16).

Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to find a ready solution. But to write such a script is not difficult. Make a workpiece in the form of the font map, but with empty fields. Use imagettftext to insert symbols in these fields.